# Using SharpSvn to retrieve log revisions got Disk issue

Tags: c#, wcf, svn, sharpsvn

I'm workin on a wcf service to get some info of svn log.
My service method:

```
public List<SvnLogInfo> ViewLog(Executable ejecutable) {
        Configuration config = m_context.Configuration.SingleOrDefault();
        if (config != null) {
            SvnClient svnClient = new SvnClient();
            SvnRevisionRange svnRevisionRange = new SvnRevisionRange(ejecutable.SvnRevisionFrom, ejecutable.SvnRevisionTo);
            SvnLogArgs args = new SvnLogArgs(svnRevisionRange);
            Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> logCollection;
            svnClient.GetLog(config.RepositoryPath, args, out logCollection);
            List<SvnLogInfo> logInfo = new List<SvnLogInfo>();
            foreach (SvnLogEventArgs log in logCollection) {
                logInfo.Add((SvnLogInfo)log);
            }

            return logInfo;
        }
        return null;
    }

[Serializable]
public class SvnLogInfo  {


    public SvnLogInfo() {
    }

    private string m_message;

    public string Mensaje {
        get { return m_message; }
        set { m_message = value; }
    }

    private string m_author;

    public string Autor {
        get { return m_author; }
        set { m_author = value; }
    }



    public static explicit operator SvnLogInfo(SvnLogEventArgs e) {
        SvnLogInfo info = new SvnLogInfo();
        info.Mensaje = e.LogMessage;
        info.Autor = e.Author;
        return info;
    }
}
```

It works, but when excetuing this line:

```
svnClient.GetLog(config.RepositoryPath, args, out logCollection);
```

Throws me this error message:

[image: There is no disk in drive G]

There is no disk in drive G.

As I mention, I'm using SharpSvn library. Is there a way to solve this issues?. By the way, the variable `config.RepositoryPath` has this value `"C:\Users\carlos.vega.CONTAPERU\Desktop\Solucion ContaNet v3 Espero Funcione"`

Comment: I think this error is caused by a Build probleem of a fee lees recent SharpSvn version that accidentally have a hardcoded configutation path in the OpenSSL support. Can you try a more recent SharpSvn?

Comment: Hi, I'm using the lastest version of SharpSvn

Comment: I can't think of a single last version. Would that be a 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8 or experimental 1.9 based release. A continuous integration build or a daily... or a blessed release. Or maybe even one from NuGet. Todays last builds are not the same as yesterdays. Posting a version number works much better as it answers all that.